# Gson Custom Deserializer is not working for String Array

Tags: android, gson, realm

I am using Realm as database but it cannot save String Array directly.So, I have to convert it into custom object before save. That's why I am writing custom deserializer. However, I find that the deserializer didn't catch the json during debug. (But I change the String[].class to String.class, it catches "Peter")

Now my json from server is

`{

   "name":"Peter",
   "role":[

      "user",
      "admin"
   ]
}`

Code of registering deserializer for handling String Array:

```
Gson gson =
   new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(String[].class, new ListStringResponseDeserializer())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using http://realmgenerator.eu - paste your JSON there and you will get your custom object to store strings (but you have to check the *"use classes RealmInt and RealmString for primitive arrays"* checkbox).
Then create Gson object using GsonBuilder like here https://gist.github.com/jocollet/91d78da9f47922dc26d6

Comment: Answer accepted for https://gist.github.com/jocollet/91d78da9f47922dc26d6 as it did catch the json and deserialize as what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not an array of strings, it's an object containing an array of strings. You can deserialize it like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

class Test {

    class Root {
        String name;
        String[] role;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // JSON from question
        String json = "{\n"+
                "\n"+
                "   \"name\":\"Peter\",\n"+
                "   \"role\":[\n"+
                "\n"+
                "      \"user\",\n"+
                "      \"admin\"\n"+
                "   ]\n"+
                "}\n"+
                "\n";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Root root = gson.fromJson(json, Root.class);
        System.out.println(root.name);
        for (String s: root.role) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Peter
user
admin
```